# Inserting a lot of data in table with EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have a user table with **+100000** users in it. 
If I want to create a row for each of these users in another table with `EF`, what is the best approach for this?

I'm guessing looping all the users in `C#` and creating **100000** instances of my table row item could be something I'd regret.

Should I create a `stored procedure`? What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: The best would be implementing this is Sql Server itself. Implement it as a stored proc and execute via the stored commands.

Comment: Due to change tracking and other reasons (that I don't fully understand) inserting a lot of data with EF is excruciatingly slow. The best way to solve it is not using EF, using the bulk insert in the answer below or (depending on your perspective the best or the worst solution) accept the slowness, let it run, and go out for drinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went on Giorgi's solution. A very simple SP that inserted 102400 rows in under two seconds.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1 col2, UserID)
SELECT @Param1, @Param2, [ID] FROM [User]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a bulk data insert extension for entity framework, download and see docs here:
https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/

Add it with NuGet:

EF4

PM> Install-Package EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef4
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef4

EF5

PM> Install-Package EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef5
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef5

EF6

PM> Install-Package EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6

Comment: But this still means I need to instantiate 100k entities to bulkinsert witch would possibly mean an OutOfMemoryException, right?

Comment: You may be able to do a single LINQ query that selects from one data source and then bulk inserts into the new data source.